# sd card won't mount when an android phone is connected after 12.10 fresh install

Tags: 12.10, android, sd-card

I just upgraded to 12.10 via a fresh install. Mounting my Xperia Neo V in 12.04 worked flawlessly however I just discovered that the sd card can't be detected and mounted in 12.10. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

P. S. I can mount it via a card reader though and it mounts ok in Windows 7. So it surely can't be hardware related.

EDIT: Sony Ericsson Neo V running Android 2.3.4. USB mass storage is already turned on.

Comment: is it android phone? if yes, have you turned on USB Mass Storage option.

Comment: Is the phone using Android **v2.3.x** (Gingerbread) or have you upgraded to **v4.0.x** (Ice Cream Sandwich)?

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step protocol of what you do to connect the phone.

Comment: I plug in the sd cable to both phone and laptop. Windows 7 easily mounts (12.04 too) the sd card but for some strange reason, 12.10 can't

Comment: run lsusb and post the output

Comment: Lsusb is the same before I plug in and after I unplug. Just does not recognize any new device or hardware

Comment: I solve this problem. You must check in Settings / Xperia / Connection / USB connection mode / MSC Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a kernel regression. This [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1065964) covers the issue. Let's hope Canonical squashes this bug A.S.A.P.

EDIT:

Yet to verify but according to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1047527), the bug has been fixed. Update to the latest Ubuntu kernel via `Software updater` to rectify this problem.

Bug has been fixed with the latest kernel update

Answer (score 2):

Try connecting the phone with the computer first.

Then change the connection type to mass-storage.

Wait for some time like 5 minutes.

If it is still not working then try this..

Pull the usb cable just a little bit out from the computer side.. ( just a tiny bit) and wait for a couple of minutes..

if it starts working then you may push the usb - cable back in properly.

I faced similar issue..

If it still doesn't work then :(

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately

Comment: The phone charges even though a usb connection can't be detected

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered the same issue with my Fly DS210 mobile phone with a SD-card. After plugging into the USB, it asks to choose the operating mode: flash-drive, webcam, serial, etc. After I choose `Flash-drive`, the phone hangs, nothing mounts and there appears a strange empty mounted directory inside `/media`.

The solution that worked in my case, was to uninstall the `usb_modeswitch` package. It handles such multipurpose devices, and switches them from `usb-storage` to `usbserial` mode.

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Sony Ericsson Xperia ray connected by usb with my laptop running Ubuntu Gnome Remix 12.10. Tested with Suse 12.2 and (*brrrrr*) Windows XP - no problem there.
After the news that Canonical would take over responsibility for kernel 3.5, I got the idea to update to a kernel from the 3.6-branch. I took the kernel 3.6.6 from UpUbuntu http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/11/install-linux-kernel-366-in-ubuntu.html and now it works again. The SD-card on my phone is showing up on the laptop and the phone is showing contact to the computer.

Comment: It definitely makes sense as I'm sure Canonical did something to the Linux kernel which causes this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with my Xperia Ray ICS because USB-connection mode was not set to mass storage. Now it works.

Comment: This won't work with newer versions of android, but if Android offers UMS mode then by all means this is the best option.